# Effective approximation of a real number by elements of a number field?

Tags: nt.number-theory

How do I go about finding an epsilon-approximation of a given real number x
by an element of minimal or near-minimal height from a given number field K?

It would suffice for my purposes to solve this for real quadratic extensions of Q.

Case of primary interest is actually K = Q(sqrt(2)).

Thanks.
Alex--

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by the LLL algorithm. (See, e.g., http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm#Applications and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_relation_algorithm)